# How to test access to /create?

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I am trying to write a Feature test to check permissions accessing the CRUD for my model ('company'), but it is returning a 500 error instead of the expected 200.

My code is as follows:

```
    public function testCompaniesOfficeAdmin()
    {
        $this->office_admin = User::factory()->create();
        $this->office_admin->assignRole('office administrator');
        Auth::guard(config('backpack.base.guard'))->login($this->office_admin);

        $response = $this->actingAs($this->office_admin, 'web')->get('/company');
        $response->assertStatus(200);

        $response = $this->actingAs($this->office_admin, 'web')->get('/company/create');
        $response->assertStatus(200);
    }
```

The first assertion works as expected, but the second one fails with a 500 error complaining about

> ErrorException: array_filter() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in file  /.../vendor/backpack/crud/src/app/Library/CrudPanel/Traits/SaveActions.php on line 52

My guess is that it's somehow trying to save data when I access /company/create, which I would expect for a POST but not for a GET.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can't do a get when you are trying to test a post, that's why you're getting the 500 error in the first place. For the create test, you should do a post call with some mocking data in the format expected by the post request.

Comment: @Gi1ber7 the op is testing access to the page that allows the create action. Viewing the page is in fact a GET request.

Answer (score 1):

If we look in `vendor/backpack/crud/src/app/Library/CrudPanel/Traits/SaveActions.php` on the line mentioned in the error, we see this function:

```
/**
 * Gets the save action that has the desired order.
 *
 * @param int $order
 * @return array
 */
public function getSaveActionByOrder($order)
{
    return array_filter($this->getOperationSetting('save_actions'), function ($arr) use ($order) {
        return $arr['order'] == $order;
    });
}
```

What this function is doing getting the available save actions for this button on the create page:

[image]

The fact that you get this error tells us that `$this->getOperationSetting('save_actions')` is returning `null`.

As for why that returns null, I would check if the application is modifying the `save_actions` settings anywhere and start looking there. We might be able to further help if you post your full CRUD controller code.